# Captcha image not displaying on remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with my Captcha image. It's working fine on my local system but not on remote server. Recently we shifted server that was working fine in previous server. I didn't miss any references. Please reply soon

Comment: Are you finding anything in your error logs? You have not given much to go on here.

Comment: recheck that you moved the captcha dll too.

Answer (score 0):

Check your eventlog or other logs. have you Tried acessing the page inside the server and see if it is opening internally ?

Are the servers load balanced ?

Comment: Yes I tried on server also...Its not displaying in server too..yes it is balanced

Comment: Also are you using any javascript or jquery for captcha ? or any script errors in the page while loading ?